# Treeview with dropdown sublist in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm styling an HTML treeview with CSS and I'm trying to make sublists apear sliding down when expanding a node.

Here is my *simplified* **index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="node">
      Div-1
      <div class="children">
        <div class="node">
          Div-1-1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="node">
      Div-2
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the **script.js** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.node').click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).toggleClass('expanded');
  });
});
```

And the **style.css** :

```
.node {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.node > .children {
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in;
}
.node.expanded > .children {
  display: block;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

The result (see. [plunkr1](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kc5we48hXR5NB93Uf5K3?p=preview)) is fine BUT the sublist is not sliding down, it's the rest of the tree that is sliding down revealing the sublist.

So I tried something else, I wrapped the "children" div :

```
<body>
  <div class="node">
    Div-1
    <div class="childrenWrapper">
      <div class="children">
        <div class="node">
          Div-1-1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="node">
    Div-2
  </div>
</body>
```

And changed the CSS :

```
.node {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.node > .childrenWrapper {
  border: solid 1px lightblue;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.node > .childrenWrapper > .children {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}
.node.expanded > .childrenWrapper > .children {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Now (see. [plunkr2](http://plnkr.co/edit/MH8YaBSb9FwyJQ0UWPgW?p=preview)) the sublist is properly sliding, BUT the wrapping div with the needed overfow hidden keeps the size of the sublist wich is pretty ugly.

I can't find a solution to this issue. Any idea ?

Comment: I tried to combine both methods, BUT the synchronization of both transitions is a nightmare and won't work for every size of tree...

Comment: Do you need the sublist to slide over the parent? As in covering Div-2?

Comment: @DarkAshelin No I need the sublist to slide down like appearing from under the Div-1, pushing down the Div-2.

Comment: Then your first plunkr should be the correct way to go. The sliding shown here is just how the DOM works.

Comment: @DarkAshelin Well to be precise, to effect is not correct, the sublist is not sliding down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change CSS like this :

```
.node > .childrenWrapper {
    transition:height .5s;
    height: 0;
}
.node.expanded > .childrenWrapper {
    height:auto;
}
```

And JS like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.node').click(function (event) {
        var $e = $(this),
            $childrenWrapper = $e.find('.childrenWrapper'),
            $children = $e.find('.children'),
            h = $e.is('.expanded') ? 0 : $children.height(); // target height depending on it being expanded or not.
        $childrenWrapper.height(h); // applying height to the childrenWrapper (see css transition on .node > .childrenWrapper)
        $(this).toggleClass('expanded');
    });
});
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/49te34wx/

And by the way : `$(event.target).toggleClass('expanded');` could be `$(this).toggleClass('expanded');`

Comment: Yeah, it's closer. IT's what I described in my first comment as "combining both methods" but the height has no transition so the Div-2 it instantly pushed down while the sublist slides down slowly which doesn not look good.

And by the way, thanks for the jQuery advise :)

Comment: Then, as you cannot make transition from or to 'auto', you will need more JS to get and apply children's height to its wrapper ... I've edited my answer

Comment: Your solution rocks. Setting dynamically the height of the wrapper to synchronize transitions is the way to go... using jQuery. This was my backup solution as I'm asked to do it with pure CSS. (The jQuery used in my example is just here to simulate the class change)

Comment: If I don't get a pure CSS solution by the end of tomorrow, the resolution point is yours ;)